# Creating color table file in PCI Geomatica

Tags: raster, classification, color, representation, geomatica

What is the simplest way to create a stand-alone color-table file in PCI Geomatica (PCT or STR)? I have some classified imagery with values ranging between 0-255 and I would like a way to automatically have them consistently colored the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found a suitable solution myself. I can create a text file with space separated values following the format "raster_value r g b" (without the quotes) which correspond to the raster value and the desired rgb color components I want to use to color it. Then I can use PCTREAD to read in the .txt file to a PCT layer in the .pix file.